# Mathematical properties of Minkowski spacetime(3+1) and its isometry group

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions, semi-riemannian-geometry

I would like to clarify if the Minkowski subspace of points inside the null hypersurface (light-cones) at each point's tangent space is just a homogeneous subspace(transitive under G) for the Poincare group G(meaning the semidirect product of translations and the proper orthochronous Lorentz group) or a principal homogeneous subspace(G-torsor), i.e. simply transitive under G.

I would tend to think that the physical notion of the special relativistic principle with a constant c at each frame means velocities of massive particles can be boosted from any point inside each of the future light cones to any other point's lightcone preserving the space, and this would imply that the action of the Poincare group on the bundle of future timelike directions is not just transitive but simply transitive, is this assumption flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments seem to justify transitivity, but not the other half of simple transitivity, which is freedom/uniqueness. Given any distinct $v,w$ in the future light cone, there will be many different Lorentz transformations sending $v$ to $w$: if you let $\phi$ be a boost such that $\phi(v)=w$, then we also have $R\circ\phi(v)=w$ for any spatial rotation $R$ about $w$.

Indeed, it's clear just from dimension counting that (a subspace of) Minkowski space can't be a torsor for such a big group.

Comment: By the Poincare group I was referring to the semidirect product of the proper orthochronous Lorentz group and the group of translations of Minkowkski spacetime(sorry I should have been more precise, it's now edited) so the composition that you mention wouldn't be valid as it wouldn't preserve orientation.

Comment: @bonif: the proper orthochronous component $SO^+(3,1)$ already contains both boosts and rotations, no?

Comment: I've also been talking about the Lorentz group rather than the Poincaré group, since translations doesn't preserve the lightcone and thus there isn't a well-defined action of the Poincaré group on the set you're talking about.

Comment: Oops, you are right that specifying the identity component of the Lorentz group changes nothing about the correctness of your answer, I managed to confuse myself. But I don't think you are right about your comment on translations not preserving the interior of lightcones. Certainly any physics textbook about the subject mention that the principle of relativity implies that the Poincare group acts
transitively on the bundle of future-timelike directions of Minkowski specetime.

Comment: Of course the translations don't allow timelike vectors to become lightlike or spacelike if that's what you mean.

Comment: @bonif: perhaps there's some confusion here - your post seemed to me to be talking about the single future lightcone of Minkowski space, i.e. the 4-dimensional set $\{ p \in \mathbb R^{3,1} : \eta(p,p) < 0 \}.$ If you're instead talking about the bundle $\{ (p,v) \in T\mathbb R^{3,1} : \eta(v,v) < 0 \}$ of future lightcones of each tangent space, then yes, the Poincaré group acts transitively, but still not simply transitively - the group has 2 more dimensions.

Comment: Right, your second description was what I meant, sorry I used a misleading wording, I've edited now. Thanks!